# What is a contracting grammar (in opposition to a non-contracting grammar)?

Tags: formal-grammars, chomsky-hierarchy

In the Chomsky hierarchy what is corresponding to a contracting grammar?

I can find references to non-contracting grammars (which can be transformed into context-sensitive grammars accordingly to what Wikipedia is saying: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar), but I don't know what would correspond to a contracting grammar

My guess would be unrestricted grammars (Type-0 in the Chomsky hierarchy) but I would like confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Unrestricted grammars (type-0) have productions $\alpha\to\beta$ with $\alpha$ containing at least one nonterminal.

For noncontracting (or monotonic) the condition $|\alpha|\le |\beta|$ is added.

I would not use the term "contracting" for what you try to express, though. That suggests that strings become shorter during derivations. Which is hard if one starts with a single symbol axiom. "not necessarily contracting" perhaps?

A similar problem occurs with automata terminology. A nondeterministic finite state automaton may very well be deterministic.